# SQL check for null values during CASE statement

Tags: sql-server

Below Code works fine, when we get values as expected

```
  case Criteria    
  when ''Security_Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Arranger'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1)     
  when ''Group'' then criteriavalue
  else substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1)     
  end as CriteriaValue
```

But in somecase CRITERIAVALUE above comes blank/NULL..

How to change the above so that it shows values (means CRITERIAVALUE field) when its not null.. and When null then ignore the SUBSTRING

Comment: Why do you have '' everywhere? Is this code embedded in your application? For the question at hand you need to look at your else. You have two criteria there. One where it is > '' and then the else.

Comment: we are using '' as this is dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
Add a WHEN statement as the first evaluation in the CASE to output NULLs separate.

```
WHEN CriteriaValue IS NULL then 'WHATEVER YOU WANT NULLS TO BE'
```

Option 2:
use `ISNULL(CRITERIAVALUE,'Some Text Here')` in place of all `CRITERIAVALUE` if you would like to replace the null with a static text value.

Comment: Option 2 is safe bet.

Comment: @Richard, if you click the little `HELP` question mark in the upper right corner of the Answer box, it'll give you some pointers on formatting your answers (or questions, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

check the criteria value before you check the criteria

```
case when criteriavalue is not null then
 case Criteria    
  when ''Security_Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Arranger'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1)     
  when ''Group'' then criteriavalue
  else substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1)     
  end  
end as CriteriaValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `iif` like below:

```
case Criteria    
  when ''Security_Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Agent'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue,14)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue,8)-1)    
  when ''Arranger'' then substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1)     
  when ''Group'' then criteriavalue
  else iif(criteriavalue IS NULL, NULL, substring(criteriavalue,charindex(''['',criteriavalue)+1,charindex('']'',criteriavalue)-charindex(''['',criteriavalue)-1))     
  end as CriteriaValue
```